# Remove low frequency items from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I am playing a little with [Last.fm](http://www.dtic.upf.edu/~ocelma/MusicRecommendationDataset/lastfm-360K.html) dataset. The dataset is consisting of user id, artist name, and number of plays. something like this:

```
    user                                        artist                  plays
0   00000c289a1829a808ac09c00daf10bc3c4e223b    betty blowtorch         2137
1   00000c289a1829a808ac09c00daf10bc3c4e223b    die Ärzte               1099
2   00000c289a1829a808ac09c00daf10bc3c4e223b    melissa etheridge       897
3   00000c289a1829a808ac09c00daf10bc3c4e223b    elvenking               717
4   00000c289a1829a808ac09c00daf10bc3c4e223b    juliette & the licks    706
```

Now, what I want to do is to clean this data up a bit. Since many of the names are incorrect, I want to **remove artists that are played less than say 50 times by all users**.

I guess, I should use *groupby* and try to count them. But since I am a bit new to pandas and my dataset is very big, I wanted to know what would be the best practice for removing these items.

*tl;dr:*
**What is the best way to remove lowest occurring artists?**

**PS** (edit):
The desired output would be a dataframe with the same schema as the input, without the artists that has been played (**Sum of their plays on all users**) less than a certain number.

**PS2**:
For example I have this dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'user': 3 * ('abc'),
    'artist': 3 * ('metallica', 'coldplay', 'dfj'),
    'plays': [100,24,0,48,135,10,62,38,2]
})
```

So we have this dataframe:

```
    user    artist      plays
0   a       metallica   100
1   a       coldplay     24
2   a       dfj           3
3   b       metallica    48
4   b       coldplay    135
5   b       dfj          10
6   c       metallica    62
7   c       coldplay     38
8   c       dfj           2
```

Now "dfj" *has been played only 15 times overall*. I want to remove "dfj" and return something like this:

```
    user    artist      plays
0   a       metallica   100
1   a       coldplay     24
3   b       metallica    48
4   b       coldplay    135
6   c       metallica    62
7   c       coldplay     38
```

Comment: how much time is your groupby and count taking?

Comment: Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: @experiment it does not take much time on this dataset, maybe two minutes. I just wanted to know the best practice as I was going to work on much bigger data later.

Comment: @AmirAghdam, What is the desired output  based on your the post?

Comment: @jezrael How about now? :)

Comment: @AmirAghdam - Really good, my answer was edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for Series with aggregate values with same size like original `DataFrame`:

```
print (df.groupby('artist')['plays'].transform('sum'))
0    210
1    197
2     12
3    210
4    197
5     12
6    210
7    197
8     12
Name: plays, dtype: int64

df1 = df[df.groupby('artist')['plays'].transform('sum') > 50]
print (df1)
        user     artist  plays
0  abcabcabc  metallica    100
1  abcabcabc   coldplay     24
3  abcabcabc  metallica     48
4  abcabcabc   coldplay    135
6  abcabcabc  metallica     62
7  abcabcabc   coldplay     38
```

Answer (score 0):

simplest to try, based on the understanding from the post.

```
>>> df
                                       user                artist  plays
0  00000c289a1829a808ac09c00daf10bc3c4e223b       betty blowtorch   2137
1  00000c289a1829a808ac09c00daf10bc3c4e223b             die Ärzte   1099
2  00000c289a1829a808ac09c00daf10bc3c4e223b     melissa etheridge    897
3  00000c289a1829a808ac09c00daf10bc3c4e223b             elvenking    717
4  00000c289a1829a808ac09c00daf10bc3c4e223b  juliette & the licks    706
```

Result:

```
>>> df[(df['plays'] >897)]
                                       user           artist  plays
0  00000c289a1829a808ac09c00daf10bc3c4e223b  betty blowtorch   2137
1  00000c289a1829a808ac09c00daf10bc3c4e223b        die Ärzte   1099
```